# Python - Kivy - Builtdozer : Having a button call the android keyboard

Tags: android, python, kivy

Framework: I am talking about an Android app written in Python 2.7 and packaged with Builtdozer

I have a Builder inside the app with a button

```
Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    Button:
                        text: str(root.name)
                        font_size: '20sp'
                        pos_hint: {'x':.0, 'y':.3}
                        size_hint: .4, .8
''')
```

I want to create a function, `change_name`, that,  if I press the above button, opens the android keyboard to accept an user `raw_input`

The `raw_input` provided by the user has to replace the text of the above button.

What I thought is:

1) Create a variable `name = StringProperty('Me')`

2) Create a function:

```
def change_name(self):
    self.name = raw_input()
```

3) Call the function inside my button with a `on_release`

```
Builder.load_string('''
    FloatLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        Button:
                            text: str(root.name)
                            font_size: '20sp'
                            pos_hint: {'x':.0, 'y':.3}
                            size_hint: .4, .8
                            on_release: root.change_name() 
    ''')
```

It is correct? Because actually, running the app on Ubuntu, I am trying to click on the button but the app does not ask for an input (it seems blocked).

As a consequence I believe it will not work also on Android.

Could you please help me understanding where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` allows to get input from ***stdin*** (terminal). On Android you will not have the terminal available. In addition, **`raw_input` is blocking**, this causes the main event loop of your app to be freeze and will cause your app to stop responding.

You shouldn't use `raw_input` but Kivy's own methods.

On the other hand, you want to make your button editable (as if it were a `TextInput`). You can create your own custom Button class or use [WindowBase.request_keyboard()](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.request_keyboard) to request the keyboard manually. However, you can do a little trick by hiding a `TextInput` and use it to enter the text:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

kv_text= ('''
<MyWidget>:
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: 'Hello'
            font_size: '20sp'
            pos_hint: {'x':.0, 'y':.3}
            size_hint: .4, .8
            on_release: root.change_name(self)

        Button:
            text: 'World'
            font_size: '20sp'
            pos_hint: {'x':0.6, 'y':.3}
            size_hint: .4, 0.8
            on_release: root.change_name(self)
''')


class MyWidget(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hide_input = TextInput(size_hint=(None,  None),
                                    size = (0, 0),
                                    multiline = False)
        self.hide_input_bind = None

    def change_name(self,  instance):
        if self.hide_input_bind:
            self.hide_input.unbind_uid('text',  self.hide_input_bind)

        self.hide_input.text = instance.text
        self.hide_input.focus = True
        self.hide_input_bind = self.hide_input.fbind('text',  self._update_text,  instance)

    def _update_text(self, button,  instance,  value):
        button.text = value



class MyKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

def main():
    Builder.load_string(kv_text)
    app = MyKivyApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**App working on Android** (Kivy Launcher):

[image]