# Python - comparison between 2 apps with a very similar codebase - 'TypeError: change_name() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)' only in one

Tags: android, python, kivy, typeerror

The starting point of the discussion is the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911038/python-kivy-builtdozer-having-a-button-call-the-android-keyboard).

The subject was "How to call the Android keyboard from a Kivy application"

The answer provided me with works perfectly if alone, but I have tried to reuse the code provided me with into a more complex app and it is not working.

In details: the app is running but when i click on the `Button` that has to run the function `change_name` I receive the following error `TypeError: change_name() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

This is the `Button`

```
Button:
    text: "Me"
    font_size: '20sp'
    pos_hint: {'x':.0, 'y':.3}
    size_hint: .4, .8
    on_release: root.change_name()
```

This is the `change_name` function inside the related class `LifeCounter`

```
class LifeCounter(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LifeCounter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hide_input = TextInput(size_hint=(None, None),
                                    size=(0, 0),
                                    multiline=False)
        self.hide_input_bind = None

    def change_name(self, instance):
        if self.hide_input_bind:
            self.hide_input.unbind_uid('text', self.hide_input_bind)
        self.hide_input.text = instance.text
        self.hide_input.focus = True
        self.hide_input_bind = self.hide_input.fbind('text', self._update_text, instance)

    def _update_text(self, button, instance, value):
        button.text = value
```

Below the full traceback

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "app.py", line 182, in <module>
     MtgLifeCounter().run()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 828, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 663, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 405, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 293, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8146)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:14035)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1109, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:12816)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
 TypeError: change_name() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Consider that I am new to programming, and some concepts are not totally clear to me and this case is an example: I have two apps with the same main class (only the name is different) but in one case is running and in the other no.

Could you please help me understanding what is the difference from the two apps and why I am receiving an error in the case below if the function `change_name` that I am calling with a `Button` is the same?

Comment: This error usually is a result of trying to call a method on a class, instead of on a class __instance__. So `MyWidget.change_name(foo)` vs `MyWidget().change_name(foo)`. With a class instance, python inserts a reference to the instance itself as the first argument to the method call. By convention this is called `self`.

Comment: If you want help finding this bug, you should include the full traceback and only relevant code. Read this: [mcve]. The traceback tells you where the error was triggered.

Comment: Thank you, I will read the article and edit the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you have

```
on_release: root.change_name(self)
```

In the second example you have this instead:

```
on_release: root.change_name()
```

You have to call `change_name()` with the required number of arguments. Presumably, you want to use `root.change_name(self)` there as well.